# Java toString Issue

Tags: java, arrays, list, generics, tostring

I am having an issue with the `toString` method in `Java`. Here's the run down... I have a database that I am querying. The query returns all of the members in the database, and I'd like to return these members as a string. Here's what I've done so far.

In the `Member class` I have the following

```
 @Override 
 public String toString()
 {
    return this.login_name + " (" + this.lastName + ", " + this.firstName + ")";
 }
```

Now, to get the members from the database and return them as an array of strings, here's what I have:

```
/**
 * Accessor used to get all of the user names contained in the underlying
 * database.
 * @return String[] user_names - The names of all the users in the data base.
 * @throws MemberNotFoundSignal
 */
public String[] getMembers() throws MemberNotFoundSignal
{
    List<Member> members = Arrays.asList(this.rscMgr.getAllMembers());

    String[] user_names = new String[members.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < members.size(); i++)
    {
        user_names[i] = members.get(i).toString();
    }

    return user_names;
}
```

At run time `members.get(i).toString()` should invoke the toString method from the Member class (am I mistaken)? If I'm not, why would the objects toString method be invoked on this? It's my understanding that by converting the array to a List, it will utilize the Member's toString method (because of generics).

I'm using this code as follows:

```
String[] user_names = this.model.getMembers();
this.memberInput = new JComboBox(user_names);
```

When I set a breakpoint on the `getMembers` function the 'user_names' doesn't contain the overriden version of the string that I expect, but instead the objects default return type.

The `members.get(i).toString();` doesn't call upon the overridden toString method, but instead calls upon the objects implementation.

Comment: Did you run it? Can you give an example `Member` and what the `toString` prints from outside the List and inside the List? Without such information, I cannot tell what might be wrong.

Comment: Why are you turning your array into a list into an array? What's wrong with just using `getAllMembers()`?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel `getAllMembers()` returns an array of all of the Member objects which correspond to all of the members in the database.

Comment: Yes it will totally work assuming this.rscMgr.getAllMembers() takes whatever you get out of the database and convert them into Member objects.  If it doesn't you're hosed though.

Comment: I get that, but why are you transforming it into a `List`? Why not just loop over the array returned by `getAllMembers()`?

Comment: @Jonathan I believe his point is that you are not gaining anything by translating your `Member[]` array into a `List<Member>`.  The semantics of method overriding do not require you to place the items into a list; the elements need not even be typed as `Member` for this to work (the runtime type is used; not the declared type at compile time).  What behavior are you seeing?  What is the runtime type of these `Member` objects?  Is it possible they are a subclass of `Member` which themselves override `toString()`, thus superseding your own override?

Comment: @MikeStrobel I was originally looping over the array returned by the `getAllMembers()` function, but the `toString` method overridden in the Member class doesn't apply to the array, so thats why I converted to the list (I know it seems redundant). At runtime the Members `toString` method is running the objects implementation (almost as if I hadn't overridden it at all).

Comment: Jonathan: your code should work. Please show how you output this code.

Comment: @Jonathan Something is wrong; there should be no difference in the results between iterating over an array vs. a list.  If you are seeing the results produced by `Object#toString()`, then the JVM may not be loading the correct version of your `Member` class.   Evaluate this at runtime and see where the class is being loaded from: `Member.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource()`.  Make sure the class file is up to date with the source.

Comment: Does the `toString()` method work correctly when you create a `Member` object manually and call it?

Comment: Just to be sure: you're not calling `String[].toString()`, right?

Comment: @Keikoku Yes, I manually tested the Member class and it works fine. Its almost as if there is some intermediate issue, but there isn't any code in between that would cause an issue.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Yeah I'm not calling on any `toString` outside of the `Member toString`

Comment: @Jonathan Have you set a breakpoint where you call `getMembers()` and stepped into the method to make sure you're calling the right code?  Have you inspected the result (`user_names`) before stepping out of the method?

Comment: @Jonathan: just edit your post to show how you are actually outputting, please.

Comment: @MikeStrobel Yes sir, it goes right to my overridden method. But when it returns the output isn't the string that it should be, but instead it is of the objects toString return type.

Comment: See my edited post above for context.

Comment: And you've verified that you are calling the same `getMembers()` method that you quoted above?  What does `user_names` look like before you pass it into the `JComboBox` constructor?  Set a breakpoint and inspect it with the debugger.  Also, search your code for any other places where the `memberInput` field is assigned!

Comment: @MikeStrobel It contains an array of the strings return by the objects default implementation.

Comment: @Jonathan And you stepped into `getMembers()` and watched it build up the string array?  Which `toString()` implementation did it call?  When you are broken _within the `getMembers()` method_ in the debugger, if you use your IDE's expression evaluator to create a new `Member` and call `toString()` on it, what value do you get?

Comment: @MikeStrobel That's the issue, its calling the `objects toString` method. But the run time type should be of the type Member. Which is why it's beyond me.

Comment: @Jonathan Look at my first comment where I tell you how to get the location of the class file that the JVM is using.  Is the location what you would expect, and is the file up to date with the source code?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41432/discussion-between-jonathan-and-mike-strobel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our chat, we determined that your JAR artifact was not being updated properly.  We determined that `Member` was being loaded from the correct *location* by evaluating the following in your debugger:

```
Member.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource()
```

But when using reflection to inspect the methods declared by `Member`, we could see that the `toString()` method was not present:

```
Member.class.getDeclaredMethods()
```

And thus we theorized that the JAR was out of date, which you confirmed by inspecting the timestamp of the JAR at your deployment site.

Comment: Like a boss. Thanks for all the help Mike!

Comment: My pleasure.  Happy debugging!

Comment: @MikeStrobel Are there tools that will tell developers that one or more dependencies may be out-of-date to avoid these problems in the future?

Comment: @Keikoku I'm not aware of any, though it wouldn't surprise me.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have the ArrayList to call the `toString()` of the member objects. You can call the `toString()` while iterating the array. Take a look at the following.

```
public String[] getMembers(){

    Member members = this.rscMgr.getAllMembers();
    String userNames[] = new String[members.length];

    for(int i=0; i<members.length; i++){
        usersNames[i] = member[i].toString();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> At run time members.get(i).toString() should invoke the toString method from the Member >class (am I mistaken)? If I'm not, why would the objects toString method be invoked on this? >It's my understanding that by converting the array to a List, it will utilize the Member's >toString method (because of generics).

Remember that generics are compile time only and implemented by erasure. You cannot use it to cast objects. I am guessing your `rscMgr.getAllMembers()` returns something other than `Member`. Try something like:

```
int count=0;
for (Member m: rsc.getAllMembers()){
   usersNames[count++] = m.toString();
}
```

Comment: The compiler should be emitting `checkcast` instructions when accessing elements from a generic list.  Even with type erasure, there is still some measure of type safety.

Comment: @MikeStrobel Yeah Mike is right. And the `getAllMembers` function does indeed return a `Member` instance, so this isn't correct.