# Java's toString Method Not Being Overridden

Tags: java, ant, overriding, tostring

I made a post earlier regarding the object's `toString` method not being overridden in a class that I defined. Here's the reference to my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20053858/java-tostring-issue).

I have a `Member class` that contains data corresponding to a person (name, phone #, birthday, etc). In my application I query a database to build an array of all the members contained in the database that meet some specific criteria. What I'm trying to do is build a `JComboBox` on this array of members, so to do this I am trying to build up an array of strings representing each user with his username, lastname, and first name (username (lastname, firstname)). For example the database will return `jzwiz (Taylor, Billy)`. To do this **I have overridden the toString method in the Member class like so**:

```
@Override 
public String toString()
{
   return this.name + " (" + this.lastName + ", " + this.firstName + ")";
}
```

And here's the code that builds up the JComboBox component:

```
String[] user_names = this.model.getMemberNames();
this.memberInput = new JComboBox(user_names);
```

The `getMemberNames` function does the following:

```
/**
 * Returns an array of all of the names and logins of the members in the 
 * database.
 * @return String[] user_names: The names and logins of all of the members in
 * the database.
 * @throws MemberNotFoundSignal
 */
public String[] getMemberNames() throws MemberNotFoundSignal
{
    CodeSource cs = Member.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource();
    Method[] methods = Member.class.getDeclaredMethods();
    
    Member[] members = this.rscMgr.getAllMembers();
    String[] user_names = new String[members.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < members.length; i++)
    {
        user_names[i] = members[i].toString();
    }
    
    return user_names;
}
```

I expected that the *members[i].toString()* would return the overridden Member.toString function, but this isn't the case.

When I debug the program the `getCodeSource` shows me the path to the jar file that is under use. **I have verified that the jar has been updated to the most recent revision (the revision including the overridden toString method), but the getDeclaredMethods function doesn't show the toString method**. Its almost as if the changes I have made haven't been reflected in the updated jar.

After I make changes I have to clean and rebuild the source via an ANT Build file, but after each build I have verified that the jar is updated to the most recent revision. What else could cause this issue? Am I looking over something simple?

**EDIT:** So here's an update. I have found that the actual compiled source isn't being updated, but when I clean and rebuild from the build file the time stamp on the jar is updating. Whats the workaround for this?

Comment: This really sounds like the packaging still isn't working. Try extracting the `.class` file from the jar and inspecting it manually with an IDE or `javap` to confirm that it's the correct version.

Comment: @chrylis Its not being updated. The time stamp is being updated because the source is still being compiled, but the actual contents of the jar aren't being updated. What would cause this?

Comment: Have you verified that it works if you use a different method name (e.g. does it work when you call it `toMemberString()`)?

Comment: @Jonathan I'm not an Ant person, so I can't guess specifics. Try a complete clean and rebuild.

Comment: try `ant -v`; that's verbose.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks for the suggestion. I did a verbose clean and rebuilt and I'm still not getting the changes that I expect.

Comment: Where did `ant` go wrong? Trace through the verbose output (or at least add it here).

Comment: Also, what is `this.rscMgr`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I'm not seeing any errors in the ant build. It successfully builds, it just doesn't update.

Comment: Sounds like your `Ant clean` is not doing its job.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what's going on; Make sure you don't have an old copy of the jar file in your `classpath`. If you're running this in a container, be sure you're cleaning out any copies of your old classes it keeps around.